# Node.js + OpenID: How to detect provider sign out?

Tags: node.js, openid

I'm currently attempting to integrate OpenID with a Node.js server by using [this library](https://github.com/havard/node-openid). Logging in is pretty straightforward, but I'm really struggling to figure out how to detect when the user signs out from their OpenID provider.

For example, I'm currently using Google as a provider. If the user signs in to my application by using Google and then signs out from Google on a different site, I need to have a way to figure this out so that I can sign them out of my application as well.

My first approach was simply to hold on to the assertion and then verify it periodically to see if it had expired. This doesn't work with OpenID since the `openid.response_nonce` should be unique to each request. I can't get a new assertion since that would require another redirect to Google, so I can't do it behind the scenes using ajax. How is this normally done using OpenID? Can it be done at all? Thanks.

Comment: The session on your website normally wouldn't be tied to their OpenID provider session like this.

Comment: Oh you're right, I just tried out a few sites with this sort of login and they don't tie their sessions to the provider. I might have to reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you to know when the user signs out; there is no such tie between a relying party (client) and provider (server) in OpenID.

The best you can do is to keep track of when assertions expire and/or reauthenticate.